# Is it OK to initialize the ByteBuffer in the Selector thread in Java NIO?

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

I have a situation where I need need to change the size of the ByteBuffer depending on what data I'm expecting to send or receive. 
From the testing I've done, it seems that if I have a ByteBuffer that holds 15 bytes for example, and I only send 1 byte, then the client receives 1 byte and 14 nulls.
I can't afford for that to happen, so I'm wondering can the work of allocating a new ByteBuffer size be done in the Selector thread, or should it be done in a worker thread?

I'm leaning towards the latter option.

The ByteBuffer for each channel is attached to the channel as part of a ChannelState object that keeps track of the current state of the channel

Comment: do you clear the buffer before using it ? also do you flip it before writing to socket ?

Comment: Yes, and yes. I've since gone with reallocating the bytebuffer from a worker thread as required. It works fine. I haven't the time to go back and test and try resolve the issue properly yet.